# Is it safe to use sencha touch default animations like Slide and Fade?

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

While i was reading through sencha touch 2 documentation regarding animations i noticed this big warning "NOTE This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework. Don't rely on its existence."

Since i was thinking on relying on these animations for my app this notice got me worried, could anyone tell me if this means that i shouldn't depend on these animations for a comercial app ? I don't want to release my app and notice that some time after it's release it's been broken because i choose to ignore this warning.

Is it safe to use them ?

Example of how i was using it :

```
viewport:{
    layout:{
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'slide',
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read this note ? On what page ?

Comment: here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.fx.animation.Slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these animations.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.anims

They are used in many Sencha examples, so you don't have to worry.

But if you stumble on this note, it means that the class is used inside the framework and is most likely to change or to be removed. That why you should not rely on it.

Comment: Just a final question, using it like i did on the example i just put there would be "wrong" ?

Comment: It's exactly the way you should use it. Then it's probably going to make use the Ext.fx.animation.Slide within the framework, but you don't need to worry about that.